# Sum values using Arrays and INDEX

Tags: arrays, excel

I have the following sample sheet:

```
1/A B       C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
2                                   
3   Points  8   4   2   1               
4                                   
5   Values  1   2   3   4   4   3   1   2
```

I'm trying to sum the 'Points' based upon the array index from the 'Values'.

My expected result from this is: **30**

Here is my formula:

```
{=SUM(INDEX($C$3:$F$3,1,C5:J5))}
```

For some reason though, this only returns the first value of the array, rather than the entire sum.

To clarify, the C# version would be something like:

```
var points = new int[] { 8, 4, 2, 1 };
var values = new int[] { 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4, 2 };

var result = (from v in values
              select points[v - 1]).Sum(); // -1 as '4' will crash, but in Excel '4' is fine
```

*Edit: Adding further clarifying example*

Another example to clarify:

Points is the array. The 'values' represents the index of the array to sum.

The example above is the same as:

```
=SUM(8, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 8, 4)
```

Comment: As sum one that does not program in C#, could you spell out the number that would get added together and the result of such addition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`INDEX` will never take its row or column parameters from arrays and then perform multiple times within one array formula contained in one cell. For this `OFFSET` will be needed.

Either

```
{=SUM(N(OFFSET($C$3,,C5:J5-1)))}
```

as an array formula.

Or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(OFFSET($C$3,,C5:J5-1)))
```

as an implicit array formula without the need for [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter].

Comment: If you could take the time to fuel my own curiosity, what results are you receiving from the sample data? I was waiting to see what results the OP expected. wadr, it is rare that a non-volatile [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) cannot replace a volatile [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) but I was hoping to see what the OP expected as a result as it is not clear (to me) from the sample data, code or formula in the question.

Comment: The result is the sum of 8, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 8, 4 which is 30 and are the values from `C3:F3` taken one by one by column indices from `C5:J5`. And as of my experience INDEX will never take its row or column parameters from arrays.

Comment: Btw.: The #C example has other indices. There the result will be 24 = sum(4, 1, 2, 8, 4, 1, 4)