# excel formulas sum over array

Tags: arrays, excel, sum

I have no clue why summing over the array formula doesn't return correct results. The formula is:

```
=SUM(INDEX($C$4:$C$12,TRANSPOSE(OFFSET(K17,0,0,1,COUNT(K17:S17)))))
```

What I want to do is select multiple values from `$C$4:$C$12` based on values in `K17:S17` and then sum it. In row `K17:S17` there might 1 to 9 positive integers (from 1 to 9), that determine which row to select from `C4:C12`.

When I use just `INDEX($C$4:$C$12,TRANSPOSE(OFFSET(K17,0,0,1,COUNT(K17:S17))))` as an array function it returns the values I want to be sumed properly. but adding sum in frot returns just the first value from this set.

Comment: Why not `{=SUM(N(OFFSET($C$4,K17:S17-1,)))}`? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38342495/sum-values-using-arrays-and-index/38343185#38343185

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to pass an array as `INDEX`'s *row_num* or *col_num* parameter, a little coercion is required:

https://excelxor.com/2014/09/05/index-returning-an-array-of-values/

Also, it's better to avoid volatile `OFFSET` constructions if possible.

`=SUM(INDEX($C$4:$C$12,N(IF({1},K17:INDEX(K17:S17,MATCH(9.9E+307,K17:S17))))))`

which, incidentally, does *not* require `CSE`.

*Edit*: if the maximum value in the range `K17:S17` is 9, we can replace `9.9E+307` with `10`:

`=SUM(INDEX($C$4:$C$12,N(IF({1},K17:INDEX(K17:S17,MATCH(10,K17:S17))))))`

Regards